# WebView is not using Cookies for loading images

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I have troubles when I want my WebView to load images that requires Cookies.

I have set my cookies on the 'CookieManager'

```
final android.webkit.CookieManager instance = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance();
instance.setAcceptCookie(true);
instance.setCookie(".example.fr", mCookies, new ValueCallback<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(final Boolean value) {
        loadWebView();
    }
});
```

The WebView is then loaded with a custom HTML string because the app is generating the proper HTML.

```
private void loadWebView() {
    // this string is an example of a generated HTML 
    String htmlContent = 
        "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
        "<html><head>" + 
        "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/style.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen, projection\"/></head>" +
        "<body><img src=\"www.example.fr/img.jpg\"/></body></html>";
    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseUrl("file:///android_asset/", htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}
```

I tried to proxy the network calls with Charles Proxy and I noticed that the request to `www.example.fr/img.jpg` had no cookie set in the headers. But, when I inspect the WebView using Chrome debbuging, I can see that the Cookies are properly under the Resources tab.

It seems that they are not used for the image downloading.

Any hints or advices to make the WebView using Cookies for resource downloading ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced with same problem, it is related with following changes: 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#BehaviorWebView

to fix it you need set:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView,true);
```